# How to save scraped contents to pandas dataframe with dynamical column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, web-scraping

I have to scrape an e-commerce web page which includes the normal elements like: price, sku etc. and a table. After scraped the elements on each link page, i scraped the table in nested loop and found the elements which i need. There are two values and as you can see the column names has to be dynamically created.

```
# loop trough all links and launch one by one
 for link in links:
 driver.get(link)
 # scrape here
 price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.page-wrap > section > div > div.content--wrapper > div > div.product--detail-upper.block-group > div.product--buybox.block > div > div.product--price.price--default > span').text
 delivery_status = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.page-wrap > section > div > div.content--wrapper > div > div.product--detail-upper.block-group > div.product--buybox.block > div > div.product--delivery > p > span').text
 image_href = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='image--element']/span/img").get_attribute('srcset')
 sku = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.page-wrap > section > div > div.content--wrapper > div > div.product--detail-upper.block-group > div.product--buybox.block > ul > li > span').text
 title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.page-wrap > section > div > div.content--wrapper > div > div.tab-menu--product.js--tab-menu > div.tab--container-list > div.tab--container.has--content.is--active > div.tab--content > div.content--description > div.content--title').text
 product_descripion_list = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.page-wrap > section > div > div.content--wrapper > div > div.tab-menu--product.js--tab-menu > div.tab--container-list > div.tab--container.has--content.is--active > div.tab--content > div.content--description > div.product--description').get_attribute('innerHTML')
 # table of attributes
 attributes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='product--properties-row']")
 
 
 titles.append(title)
 product_descripion_lists.append(product_descripion_list)
 prices.append(price)
 delivery_statuses.append(delivery_status)
 skus.append(sku)
 images.append(image_href)


 # set i 
 i = 1



 for row in attributes:
    data = {}
    cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
    data['Attribut '+str(i)+' Name'] = cells[0].text
    data['Attribut '+str(i)+' Wert'] = cells[1].text
    print(data)
    i+=1
```

then i want to add this to dataframe and created an extra dictionary:

```
#save dataframe to file
  dict = {'Name' : titles, 'Beschreibung': product_descripion_lists, 'Regulärer Preis' : prices, 'Verfügbarkeit' : delivery_statuses, 'Nummer' : skus, 'Bild' : images}


     df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

     df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Now my question is: How to add that two columns with the dynamic column names to the dataframe with its values ? Desired outcome should look like this:

| Name | Beschreibung | Regulärer Preis | Verfügbarkeit | Nummer | Bild | Attribut 1 Name | Attribut 1 Wert | Attribut 2 Name | Attribut 2 Wert | etc.

The Attribut x should be as much columns as much attributes found in the loop.

Comment: Did you want full table in pandas dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean by full table? If you mean the table which I scraped before, no. I just want the two attributes out of the table + the other elements on the page in a combined dataframe which I want to export as a excel file. Desired outcome is like I described in the question

Comment: As I understand you question First you have to create two different list of this dynamic attribute(cell[0],cell[1])  and then you can append that list to dataframe like `dataframe['dynamic attribute name']=list`

Comment: Yes but what is with other elements on page which I scraped first ? The attribute himself is not dynamic. The column name has to be dynamic. And then in the end I want to have the scraped elements with the scraped attributes in one dataframe

Comment: other elements on page which you scraped also send that element to the list and at last combine all list in one dataframe. if you give more detail like single URL I can help you more efficiently.